# Is it possible to store a reference in a std::any?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, stdany

I was trying some things and came to the following question: Is there a possibility to store references to a value in a `std::any`?

I tried the following approaches:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

auto func_by_pointer(std::any obj)
{
    *std::any_cast<int *>(obj) += 2;
}
auto modify_by_pointer(int &a)
{
    func_by_pointer(std::make_any<int *>(&a));
}

auto func_by_reference_wrapper(std::any obj)
{
    std::any_cast<std::reference_wrapper<int>>(obj).get() -= 2;
}
auto modify_by_reference_wrapper(int &a)
{
    func_by_reference_wrapper(std::make_any<std::reference_wrapper<int>>(a));
}

auto func_by_reference(std::any obj)
{
    std::any_cast<int &>(obj) *= 2;
}
auto modify_by_reference(int &a)
{
    func_by_reference(std::make_any<int &>(a));
}

int main()
{
    auto value = 3;
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    modify_by_pointer(value);
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    modify_by_reference_wrapper(value);
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    modify_by_reference(value);
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

The result is the following output:

```
3
5
3
3
```

Yet, I was expecting it to be:

```
3
5
3
6
```

Thus, passing a pointer to `value` works fine. Passing a `std::reference_wrapper` to `value` works fine as well, but passing `int&` somehow doesn't work. Did I do something wrong in my code, or is it generally not possible to store references inside a `std::any`?

Comment: By the way, didn't your compiler complain when you tried to make an `std::any` from a reference? Mine did when I tried, so I switched to pointers. (“Doc, it hurts when I do _this_.” “Then don't do _that_.”) Then looking for insight I made a search that led me here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot store references in `std::any` because, for a given type `T`, the constructor `std::any(T)` stores a value of type [`std::decay_t<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), which removes reference qualifiers:

> [[any.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/any.cons)
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>   any(T&& value);
> ```
>
> 6. Let `VT` be `decay_­t<T>`.
> 7. Requires: `VT` shall satisfy the `Cpp17CopyConstructible` requirements.
> 8. Effects: Constructs an object of type `any` that contains an object of type `VT` direct-initialized with `std::forward<T>(value)`.

Comment: @jan.sende Or pointers. They're not dangerous if they don't own dynamic resources.

Comment: @CruzJean I know. Yet, I usually write my code in a fairly functional style, which affords me the luxury of mostly dropping pointers in favour of references. Thus, if possible, I avoid pointers because I don't like the mixing of `.` and `->` access...